# A complicated puzzle

Tags: mathematics, cipher, steganography, alphametic

Can you solve this complicated puzzle?

Please post the secret word, and the explanation in your answer.
[image: Puzzle]

Hint:

> There are 3 messages/codes hidden in this image. The first message is the key to opening the second and the second is hidden in the image.

Hint #2:

> The second puzzle is hidden in the image file using steganography.

Comment: Any clues as to what the word is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is what I came up with. Pretty sure it isn't correct :D

> At first I thought that it looks like a calculation so I converted the letters to numbers (A->1, Z->26).
>  Then I was stuck at what the arrows could mean. So I just tried to increment or decrement the number by one where <- means decrement and -> means increment
>  But when you add these numbers together the word "aiboro" is the result which doesn't mean anything and you can't swap the letters to get a useful word.
>  So I just switched to the opposite: -> means decrement and <- means increment
>  Result is "eedrno". Which is "redone" when you scrabble it.
>  So is the answer "redone"?
>  **Edit:** the word is AIBORO and the note in the comment that it's capitalized tells me nothing as of now.

Going on:

> Hint 2 revealed that the second message is hidden in the image file. Downloaded the file, put it in openstego(doesn't work with other programs), success. Secret message is:
>  "The ciphered secret word is: CHMMYRFNERSHA. Congratulations for getting this far, just a bit more to go."

Final Solution:

> Doing a Caesarian Shift of the letters by 13 gives you the secret message: "Puzzles are fun". I have no idea where the 13 comes from though. Maybe because the M is the last letter in the first line of the picture and is 13th in alphabet.
>  <s>@Jojo01 Does the number 13 come from the amount of letters in the secret word?</s> *look in comments*

Comment: You came really close to solving the first puzzle, the bubble quiz gives you a word close to "aidoro." However you got one letter wrong in that word, and the letters in the bubbles are capitalized. Read the hint if you want to know what to do with that word.

Comment: As it says in the hint the first puzzle is the key to opening the second and the second is hidden in the image file.

Comment: Yeah, sorry just noticed that. I used a program called openstego to put it in the file, maybe it uses a different encoding method.

Comment: Try this with your secret key: https://futureboy.us/stegano/decinput.html
If it works tell me and I will try further

Comment: Nope it ain't able to extract it, openstego is able though.

Comment: Used openstego now and got the message. Onto the last step!

Comment: Now you just need to discover what the secret word is.

Comment: Nope it's rot13

Comment: Ah ok, googled rot13. Didn't know that it's a special well known shift